# PostgreSQL backup pg_dump not working with windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, postgresql, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a powershell script which does the following:

1. Stops a service
2. Zips a local directory
3. Performs a pg_dump of a PostgreSQL database
4. Starts the service

Running this as the local user within powershell works perfectly.

However scheduling via windows task scheduler it performs all the steps apart from (3) where it is supposed to dump the PostgreSQL database.

Any ideas? I can't understand why it works when running through powershell, but running a scheduled task does not.

Other info:

- Local user in this case is a domain user with admin rights. Task scheduler is set to run as the domain user with highest privileges.
- pgpass file exists in the correct AppData location.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Redirect the output (stdout **and** stderr) of your `pg_dump` call into a file so that you can see the error message. This is most probably a privilege problem, but without the error message you wont' be able to tell what privilege exactly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Using `| Out-File C:\path` gives me a file with nothing in it when added to the `pg_dump` statement. Is this because I am only routing the stdout and not the stderr?

Comment: I don't know Powershell, but most probably yes. In a batch file stderr is redirected using `2> output.err`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That was the problem, the error is that `pg_dump : pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "datab" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied` Which I do not quite understand when it is defined in the correct AppData location, and the script works outside of the scheduler...

Comment: Which means that either the `pgpass.conf` is not where it should be (`%APPDATA%\postgresql\pgpass.conf`) or that the information in there is incorrect.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name From what I see, it is configured correctly and in the correct location. Is there an alternative method to passing the credentials required?

Comment: you can use environment variables: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Using environment variables worked a treat, thanks. I am still baffled why the `pgpass.conf` file would not work, I set it up as described in the postgreSQL documentation and placed it in the correct location.

Comment: Maybe because `%APPDATA%` is not correctly initialized when the scheduler runs. You could output the value of the variable in your batch file to see where it points to

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Correct, I am not seeing `%APPDATA%` in the output, I am seeing it if I execute the script normally though. The scheduler is using a different admin account to run the script so perhaps this account does not have `%APPDATA%` defined at all, hence not reading `pgpass.conf`

Comment: You could define `%PGPASSFILE%` for that account to specify the location of the `pgpass.conf` file if you don't want to put the password into an environment variable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, that worked also.